# Karate: How to check attribute value in response is null

Tags: api, testing, automation, frameworks, karate

I have 2 cases to verify

Case 1: Verify attribute `lastName` is **present** in response also need to check its value is **null**

```
{
 "name" : 
   {
      "firstName" : "Peter",
      "lastName"  : null
   }
}
```

Case 2: Verify attribute is **not present** in response

```
{
 "name" : 
   {
      "firstName" : "Peter"
   }
}
```

Here, I am trying to use `karate.get('response.name.lastName')` but in both case gives back **null**

Answer (score 1):

You should really read the documentation: https://github.com/intuit/karate#null-and-notpresent

```
* def response = { "name": { "firstName": "Peter", "lastName": null } }
* match response.name.lastName == '#null'

* def response = { "name": { "firstName": "Peter" } }
* match response.name.lastName == '#notpresent'
```

Comment: I have to write only one assertion to verify.
If I use '#null', then in case its coming back with the value `"lastName" : "Thomas"` would fail. Also the case where attribute is not present in response would fail.

Comment: @MandeepRehal ok I think you want to handle both cases at the same time and your original question was not clear at all. I have marked this question as duplicate, and the linked q & a should answer all your questions. ask a new question if needed